# How to do API authorize for multi tenant application laravel

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, authorization, multi-tenant, lumen

We want to do secure API authorization for application  when API called from angular ,Mobile app.
We are developing multi tenant application

Comment: Have you looked at [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport)

Comment: Not sure about the Laravel, but jwt bearer authentication is the way to go

Comment: already tried with passport but getting this issue https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport/issues/17